# How to render dynamically created div in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am creating a div and want to render its content to html of its component

`component.ts` file

```
div = document.createElement('div');
```

`component.html` file

```
<div [innerHtml]='div'></div>
```

and it shows  `[object HTMLDivElement]` instead of div content.

Is there some way to render it properly?

Version : `Angular 2.3`

here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/h4lAGnvRZc5m6Ngi8pe0?p=preview)

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: It's not a good practice to manipulate the DOM directly. You should really leverage the Angular template syntax instead, and have the div in your HTML template, then only showing it when ready using *ngIf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the result of conversion of the div element to String type which happens when you write to innerHTML property, which needs to be a string.

As `innerHtml` property, you want to write content of the div, not HTMLDivElement itself. Something like this will work:

```javascript
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = '<h3>Hello there</h3>'

this.div = div.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

create a  and use **ngIf** in the tag.
if condition is true then **div will be displayed**.